# Value Error: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, python-imaging-library

I've tried to resize image with scipy and everything seems to work fine until I try to save the image. When I try to save image I get error that you can see in title. Full traceback is available below.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
from PIL import Image

image_path = "img0.jpg"


def load_image(img_path):
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray(img, dtype="int32")
    return data


def save_image(npdata, outfilename):
    img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(np.clip(npdata, 0, 255), dtype="uint8"), "L")
    img.save(outfilename)

array_image = load_image(image_path)

array_resized_image = scipy.misc.imresize(array_image, (320, 240), interp='nearest', mode=None)

save_image(array_resized_image, "i1.jpg")
```

Full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Playground/resize image with scipy.py", line 26, in <module>
    save_image(array_resized_image, "i1.jpg")
  File "D:/Python/Playground/resize image with scipy.py", line 16, in save_image
    img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(np.clip(npdata, 0, 255), dtype="uint8"), "L")
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2154, in fromarray
    raise ValueError("Too many dimensions: %d > %d." % (ndim, ndmax))
ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2.
```

Comment: what's the value of array_resized_image.shape (do `print(array_resized_image.shape)`?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, what versions are you running?

Comment: What do you expect when you open an image with `int32` and then store it without transformation to a `uint8`?

Comment: @ Günther Jena value of array: (320L, 240L, 3L)

Comment: @ Donkey Kong you mean scipy version? I don't know it's built in into Anaconda 2. I run print scipy.__version__ and it returns 0.16.0

Comment: @ Günther Jena I just followed tutorial I don't know what dtype is to be honest, it wasn't explained there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_resized_image` has a shape of `(320, 240, 3)` - three dimensional because red, green and blue components are stored in this way. You can use `scipy.misc.imread` and `scipy.misc.imsave` for easier handling file loading and storing, so your example boils down to this:

```
import scipy.misc

image_path = "img0.jpg"

array_image = scipy.misc.imread(image_path)
array_resized_image = scipy.misc.imresize(array_image, (320, 240), interp='nearest', mode=None)
scipy.misc.imsave("i1.jpg", array_resized_image)
```

Comment: Note: The scipy.misc image manipulation functions have all been deprecated and removed

Answer (score 3):

don't you need to convert it to a two dimensional array before doing the fromarray(... 'L')?

You can do that using a scipy function or, actually quicker, to multiply the RGB by factors. Like this

```
npdata = (npdata[:,:,:3] * [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]).sum(axis=2)
```

Comment: this makes a gray image out of an colored one. As I read the original example it is not what the author wanted?

Comment: Evidently not... However the cause of the error was from trying to use PIL.Image.fromarray(a, 'L') on a.shape (H,W,3) rather than s.shape (H,W) so I suppose if someone googles "ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2" they might be pleased to find my explanation too!!