# Monkey-patching scipy.misc.imresize

Tags: python, scipy

I just spent 20 min monkey-patching this, figured I’d share

My code calls a function `dataloader.dataloader` from a module `dataloader` which calls the function `scipy.misc.imresize`

I tried using `numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize())` as suggested [in the scipy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html), but I ran into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841540/value-error-too-many-dimensions-3-2), and since the accepted answer was to use `scipy.misc.imresize`, so that was not very helpful.

By what should I replace imresize?

Comment: my first time using the "answer your own question" option, I hope it’s formatted correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import PIL
import numpy as np
def imresize(arr, size, interp="nearest" , mode="L"):
    if len(arr.shape) == 3:
        return np.stack([imresize(arr[:,:,channel], size, interp, mode) for channel in range(arr.shape[-1])], axis=-1)
    resample_ = {'nearest': PIL.Image.NEAREST, 'lanczos': PIL.Image.LANCZOS, 'bilinear': PIL.Image.BILINEAR, 'bicubic':  PIL.Image.BICUBIC, 'cubic':  PIL.Image.BICUBIC}[interp]
    return np.array(PIL.Image.fromarray(arr,mode=mode).resize(size, resample=resample_))

dataloader.scipy.misc.imresize=imresize
```

explanation:
this functions supports all the arguments of the original imresize (translating the call to a call to PIL as suggested in the scipy documentation)

The first part is in case the image has several channels, we simply process them one at a time, and use that.